# Why does cron kick a job every minute after it is started?

Tags: unix, cron

I schedule a job to run at 1 pm, however after that it runs every minute, why?

Runtime output:

```
$ crontab -l
* 13 * * * /bin/date >> /home/user/cron_work.log
$ tail -f /home/user/cron-work.log
Sun Feb 12 13:00:01 GMT+8 2012
Sun Feb 12 13:01:01 GMT+8 2012
Sun Feb 12 13:02:01 GMT+8 2012
Sun Feb 12 13:03:01 GMT+8 2012
Sun Feb 12 13:04:01 GMT+8 2012
```

Note that, the first output is good, but not the rest. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have it set to run *every minute* of this hour.

```
* 13 * * * /bin/date >> /home/user/cron_work.log
^  ^ ^ ^ ^
|  | | | \- Run every day of the week
|  | | \--- Run every month
|  | \----- Run every day of the month
|  \------- Run only when the hour is 13 (1PM)
\---------- Run every minute
```

13:00 matches this pattern, but so does 13:01, 13:02, and so on, up to and including 13:59.  14:00 does not match.

Try this:

```
0 13 * * * /bin/date >> /home/user/cron_work.log
^  ^ ^ ^ ^
|  | | | \- Run every day of the week
|  | | \--- Run every month
|  | \----- Run every day of the month
|  \------- Run only when the hour is 13 (1PM)
\---------- Run only when the minute is 0
```

This pattern will run every day at 13:00 only.